# Android id returning errors

Tags: android, reference, eclipse-adt

Some insane thing happened to me. I cleaned the project and now I'm getting a ton of errors int the form of R.something. For some reason eclipse cannot find my references anymore but they were working fine and I have run the app a lot of times.

Now I did make some changes: I created separate layout files for some stuff because the main one was becoming too big to read (and I'm using include layout) but the errors also appear on items that I have NOT moved into a different file.

All the errors look like this:
R.id.whatever_layout same for layouts and colors.

Now I'm guessing this is a eclipse bug and I tried restarting it but it didn't solve the problem.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

I found errors in values-v11/14 but I never touched those. I dont know what to edit.

Comment: if your res folder contains some kind of error then your code wont compile and R file wont be generated. Check your console for the error , fix it. And everything will start working again.

Comment: Go to DDMS and look at the problems tab to find the errors list. Mostly it occurs due to some compile error in res files such as layouts or values

Comment: there is no error in res (at least it doesn't detect one) and as far as I know form the last code written it shouldn't be one.

Comment: Can you see your R file in gen folder? if not then believe me there is an error in your res folder. NOTE: It will not be shown as red flag or something. You have to look for it in console.

Comment: here are some steps follow them exactly. 1. Open any layout file. 2 Edit it (may be just few spaces etc). 3 Save it and as soon as you will save you will see red lines printing in console window. Just follow those lines.

Comment: nothing appears in the console (do you mean problems? there about 100 but lead me nowhere cause they point at the errors)

Comment: Come on errors are being printed in console, don't look at red flags in your source files. Try this too. Project > Properties> Android and make sure if their is any library project then its not missing. Also Java Build Path> Libraries and make sure you don't have any missing libraries.

Comment: I'm telling you the console is empty. Only the problems tab has something in it and it points to the red flags. I looked at the libraries (they are there and selected)

Comment: I found some errors in values-v11/14 but I never touched those.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change anything but 
Follow these steps:

1)Clean your Project.

2)Close Eclipse and Restart it.

3)Again Clean your Project.

4)Choose your Appropriate Target.

5)Right Click on your Project and choose Android Tools->Add Support Library

I went to same situation and this will solve your Project.

Comment: I am sorry but if you had same problem it doesn't necessarily means that he is also having same issue. I know that this problem can happen for many reasons. But if no error is being shown then the problem is with resources.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh : Let him try first.It seems to be same problem which I got.

Comment: what do you mean by choose you appropriate target? api lvl?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu : Yes , Api Level.

Comment: How do I choose my target now because I already made the project and can't find anything?